# How to combine date and time into a single datetime object?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my react native app i need to combine my date and time in to single datetime object. I used react native modal date time picker npm package for get date and time.

I have a datepicker returning a date string, and a timepicker returning a time string. When i try to combine it will give me a output as Invalid date.

```
concatDateTime = () => {

    var date = this.state.date;
    var time = this.state.currentTime;

    var dateTime = Moment(date + ' ' + time, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');

    console.log(dateTime.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
}
```

I need dateobject in ('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:s') format.

Comment: Could you show us how does your `this.state.date` and `this.state.currentTime` look like?

Comment: this.state.date : 2019-02-16 , this.state.currentTime : 8:24 PM these are the output values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify the format of your input string to let moment know how to parse it.

```js
var date = '2019-02-16';
var time = '8:24 PM';

// tell moment how to parse the input string
var momentObj = moment(date + time, 'YYYY-MM-DDLT');

// conversion
var dateTime = momentObj.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:s');

console.log(dateTime);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just click on below link,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-bmgx2p?file=index.ts

I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Still gets the same out put. 'Invalid date'

Comment: Let me know if above mentioned solution is working or not?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
let mDate = moment(data.StartDateLocal).tz("Australia/Melbourne");
let mTime = moment(data.StartTimeLocal).tz("Australia/Melbourne");
let x1 = {
    'hour':    mTime.get('hour'),
    'minute':  mTime.get('minute'),
    'second':  mTime.get('second')
}                
mDate.set(x1);
this._json.header.transactionStartDateTime = mDate.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");
```